# ADO: Setting Recordset Cursor Location returning Invalid Pointer Error?

Tags: c++, ado, sap-ase

I am getting an invalid pointer error.. and I don't get what's causing it

Here is a part of my code:

```
void MyFunction() {
    _RecordsetPtr RecPtr;

    RecPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(_Recordset));
    RecPtr->CursorLocation = adUserClient       //ERROR!!!!!!!
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)

    _ConnectionPtr ConnPtr;
    ConnPtr.CreateInstance("ADODB.Connection");
    ConnPtr->Open(....my Connection String, UserID, and Password....);

    MyFunction();

    ConnPtr->Close();
    ::CoUninitialize();
}
```

The Error Message:

```
Code = 80004003
Code Meaning = I
Source = <null>
Description = <null>
dd
```

(The description says nothing.. and also I have no idea what "I" means or why "dd" is printed out at the end,,)

There is nothing wrong with the connection string, userID, and Password, since opening the connection ptr returns no error. The error occurs when I try to open the Recordset.. Can anyone find a problem in my code?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you meant **adUseClient**. And you've not actually opened anything besides a connection with the given code. Related to [**this other question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512142/ado-recordset-object-returning-80004003-error), setting the cursor location property of recordset object has nothing to do with this. You're also not catching any exceptions in this code,so I'm curious how you contrived the error condition and messaging you're reporting.

Comment: Use `Recordset`, not `_Recordset` for the `__uuidof` argument, btw. The latter is an interface, the former a coclass. You don't create instances of interfaces; you create instances of *objects*, and request interfaces *from* them.